# How to copy a link in Firefox with a plain text decoded format to past it in Notepad

Tags: firefox, copy-paste, encoding, utf-8

Every time I try to copy a link location in Firefox and then past it in Notepad I get the encoded web adresses with numbers instead of characters, I searched a little for this problem, people seems have found a way to force Firefox to bypass the encoding by doing this:

```
network.standard-url.escape-utf8: true
```

But the problem I don't find this setting in about:config, the only result I get when i write network.standard-url in about:config page is this:

[image]

So how can I copy/past decoded data in Firefox newest versions?

**Edit: I have found the solution in another post, the setting in about:config changed and was replaced by another one:**

```
browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy;false
```

Change `false` to `true` and you will be able to copy/paste encoded links in Firefox without being forced to use a decoder.

Comment: That preference has been [removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1321705)

Comment: @DavidPostill have they replaced this preference with another ?

Comment: I've absolutely no idea.

Comment: Switch to [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Its `MIME Tools` plugin contains _URL decode_ function.

Comment: @JosefZ: Thank you that's a good alternative but i also want to directly copy/paste link in Firefox, i am looking for a way to paste the decoded link only.